# What is the indefinite integral of $|f(x)|$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that the indefinite integral of $f(x)$ is $F(x)$, where $f$ is a "nice" function (something like $x^2+x+1$ or $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$)

My question is,

what is the indefinite integral of

$$|f(x)|$$

---

I know for that $|x|$, the indefinite integral evaluates to

$$\dfrac{x|x|}{2}$$
or $$\dfrac{x^2\text{sgn}(x)}{2}$$

---

So I wonder if the integral of $|f(x)|$ evalutes to $F(x) \text{sgn}(f(x))$.

Comment: Yep I think that would be correct

Comment: Assuming the function is positive on "nice" sets, you can split the integral up and integrate either $-f(x)$ or $f(x)$. Your result is correct.

Comment: Let $f(x)=2x-1$, so we can take $F(x)=x^2-x$. Now let's go for $\int_0^1|f(x)|\,dx$. By your formula, the indefinite integral would be zero at both zero and one, so the integral would be zero – but, it isn't.

Comment: Integral curve is always continuous (unless you are integrating distributions), so you will always have to "glue" the results at every zero of $f(x)$. So you cannot usually write it down in a closed form, just piece by piece. Special cases, such as $x|x|/2$ can be simplified because you only have one "corner" and you can just start the integral in that point, thus eliminating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It equals 
$$ F(x)sgn(f(x)) + c_k$$
Every time $f(x)$ changes sign, you need a new constant $c_k$ to make up for the jump in $F(x)sgn(f(x))$, so that the whole integral remains continuous.
For example, if $f(x)=2x-1$, then $F(x)=x-x^2+c$ when $x<1/2$, but $x^2-x+c+1/2$ when $x\geq1/2$.