# Exponent of Nat. Log of Absolute Value Function

Tags: integration, trigonometry, absolute-value

If I have this expression:$$\exp\left(\ln\left|\sec(x)\right|+m\right)$$

can I rewrite it as: $$\sec(x)\exp(m)$$

with no problems? I'm making the assumption that I can drop the absolute value signs since they were only necessary to avoid negative values in the natural log function.

I'm asking because later I end up with this expression in an integral like this: $$\int \sin(2x)\left|\sec(x)\right|dx$$ and I'd like to be able to use $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ to cancel the $\cos(x)$ functions so that I can get $$\int2\sin(x)dx$$ If I drop the absolute value signs it cancels no problem. Is this allowed? Or should I use u-substitution with $u = \cos(x)$?

Comment: Thank you. Would u-substitution be effective here?

Comment: No the absolute value sign cannot be dropped. $\exp(\ln|\sec(x)|)\gt 0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}−\{x=(2n+1)\pi/2,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, but $ \sec(x)\exp(m)$ takes on negative values also. So the equivalence is false. Also this has to be integrated piecewise. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952162/what-is-the-indefinite-integral-of-fx) is related.

Comment: Write $|\sec (x)|$ as $\pm \sec(x)$ on whatever domain it positive or negative and integrate $\pm 2\sin(x)\mathrm dx$ accordingly.